# Live click and targeting a specific element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following code:

```
$("li.item").live('click',function() {
    $('#menu').animate({

    }, 500);
});
```

Now, I would like to move the character to the li.item you clicked on, but I cannot use `$(this)` as that would get the `#menu` item.

I also cannot use `li.item` as there are 60 of them on the page. Is it possible to pull the specific `li.item` I clicked on into the `animate` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("li.item").live('click',function() {
    // set the current li element to the li_item var
    var li_item = $(this);
    $('#menu').animate({
        // now we can use it in any way we choose
        li_item.addClass('hello');
    }, 500);
});
```

Try that :-)

Comment: Yup - that'll do it! Thank you - it's the little easy things that confuse me sometimes. I'll accept in 5 minutes.

Comment: Glad I could help, don't worry about the little things... I spent this morning trying to debug why one of my selectors wasn't working, I had forgotten to put the # at the front, D'oh!

Answer (score 0):

> but I cannot use $(this) as that would
>   get the #menu  item.

It would get the clicked item (`li.item`) not `#menu` (`("li.item").live('click',function() {`).

> Is it possible to pull the specific
>   li.item I clicked on into the animate
>   function?

Use `$(this)`:

```
$("li.item").live('click',function() {
    $(this).animate({
    }, 500);
});
```